# create a directory structure (with nested routes + pretty urls, ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, friendly-url

I am working on a prototyp (rails 2.2.2) to create a similiar page structure as the business directory from http://www.redbeacon.com/s/b/.

Goal should be to have the following paths: mysite.com/d/state/location/ ...which displays an index of something. So far, I did the following...

Controllers and models:

```
$ ruby script/generate controller Directories index show
$ ruby script/generate controller States index show
$ ruby script/generate controller Locations index show
$ ruby script/generate model State name:string abbreviation:string
$ ruby script/generate model Location name:string code:string state_id:integer
$ rake db:migrate
```

routes:

```
map.states '/d', :controller => 'states', :action => 'index'
map.locations '/d/:state', :controller => 'locations', :action => 'index'
map.directories '/d/:state/:location', :controller => 'directories', :action => 'index'
```

...built in the models the relations:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :states
end
```

...added actions to the controllers:

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @all_states = State.find(:all)
  end
end

class LocationsController < ApplicationController
 def index
    @all_locations = Location.find(:all)
    @location = Location.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end
end

class DirectoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @location = Location.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @all_tradesmen = User.find(:all)
  end
end
```

The States Index View

```
<h1>States#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/states/index.html.erb</p>
<br><br>
<% for state in @all_states %>
  <%= link_to state.name, locations_path(state.abbreviation.downcase) %>
<% end %>
```

The Locations Index View

```
<h1>Locations#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/locations/index.html.erb</p>
<br><br>

<% for location in @all_locations %>
  <%= link_to location.name, directories_path(location.state.abbreviation, location.name) %>
<% end %>
```

But I am stuck, I get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError in Locations#index

Showing app/views/locations/index.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `state' for #<Location:0x104725920>

Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <br><br>
4: 
5: <% for location in @all_locations %>
6:   <%= link_to location.name, directories_path(location.state.abbreviation, location.name) %>
7: <% end %>
```

Any Ideas why this error message pops up? Or generally any ideas for a better approach?

Comment: I know this is tangential to your question, but I'd really advise against using a Rails as old as 2.2.2 of you have any other choice. If you're prototyping this, it sounds like you're starting off fresh. If the 3.0 series is still too new for you, I would at least try to go to 2.3.11.

Comment: It's an existing system... but I will need to upgrade to rails 3 sooner or later, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the code you should look at is:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :states
end
```

and it should be

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

Another note, although not related to the error you are getting, Ruby programmers usually prefer `array.each` than `for item in array`.